# Не могу удалить пользователя. Он есть, а пишет что нету

Tags: linux, debian

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Создал пользователя через adduser, а теперь не могу удалить. Пишет, что нету такого пользователя, но при попытке создания пользователя с таким же именем пишет, что он есть. Что делать?

Comment: Покажите. Хочется посмотреть, что́ конкретно он там пишет.

Comment: Добавил фото...

Comment: а если так: `userdel -rf rodion`

Comment: Так же. Пишет не существует

Comment: `grep rodion /etc/passwd`;
`userdel -rf rodion`;
`useradd rodion`;
`grep rodion /etc/passwd`

Comment: Фото - https://imgur.com/a/n4bwFal

Comment: добавьте эту картинку в сам вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rodion:x:1003:1003:/home/ryzhkov-server/rodion:/bin/bash
```

похоже что юзера `rodion` изначально создавали через файл `/etc/passwd` в неверном формате, а точнее упустили описание пользователя но при этом не задав на его месте пустое место

неверно `1003:/home/ryzhkov-server/rodion`

верно `1003:ОПИСАНИЕ:/home/ryzhkov-server/rodion`

верно `1003::/home/ryzhkov-server/rodion`

Для решения проблемы просто удалите полностью строку с `rodion` в файле `/etc/passwd` и сам домашний каталог если он есть или отредактируйте эту самую строку добавив недостающее двоеточие:

```
rodion:x:1003:1003::/home/ryzhkov-server/rodion:/bin/bash
```